# What is the reason why creating induced subgraphs based on anatomical definitions doesn't seem to be a popular analytical technique?

Tags: modeling, graph-theory

I was having a discussion with some colleagues about graph theory and how it could be applied to analyzing fMRI datasets, where the matrix is a pairwise correlation matrix between pairs of region of interests (ROIs). Given that we define our ROIs anatomically by using a reference Atlas, I had asked if we could analyze the topological features of the network by parcellating ROIs into "anatomical systems", i.e. group ROI's that were part of a larger region such as the Dentate Gyrus and Field CA1, 2, and 3 under the Hippocampus system. This could be done in two ways:

1. Create induced subgraphs of ROIs in said systems and quantify the graphical metrics there
2. Group the local nodal metrics of ROIs that are in said systems and quantify the average metric for every system

My understanding is that for any network (the correlation matrix in this case), all graphical metrics are calculated at the local node level, and then averaged up to get the "global" graph metric. Thus I had reasoned that we could essentially construct subgraphs based off anatomical definitions as expained above and calculate the "local system graph metric" for every anatomical system. My colleagues have mentioned that this is never done, and granted I have done a quick literature search and could not find any published papers that have done their analysis in such a manner.

The only reason why I could think this to be the case is because since every ROI has a pairwise correlation value to every other ROI, then by parecellating the network into "anatomical systems" and calculating the graphical metric in those systems would yield no differences across systems since the same trend would be observed in all systems. I can see this to be true for the second method detailed above, but I was wondering if I could have someone confirm/reject this premise. But I still don't see method 1 either; creating induced subgraphs based off anatomical definitions.

In Response to Comment:

The correlation matrix we have is essentially treated as the weighted adjacency matrix, where the weights are the magnitude of correlation coefficeint, and so are bounded [0, 1]. Thus what I have is a fully connected, weighted, undirected adjacency matrix.

There aren't many other notable mathematical properties of the network we are studying except that it's already bounded between [0, 1]. Parameters are that each node represents a ROI defined anatomically.

So how the neuroimaging field has adopted graph theory when analyzing such matrices is that they would use a couple defined graphical metrics such as Strength and clustering coefficient. The formulae used are:

Strength:
$ S_i = \sum_{j \epsilon N} w_{ij} $ where i and j represent the node number and $w_{ij}$ is the weight of the edge connecting nodes i and j.

Clustering:
$ C_i = \frac{1}{k_i \cdot (k_i - 1)} \cdot \sum_{j,k \epsilon N}(w_{ij} \cdot w_{jk} \cdot w_{ik})^\frac{1}{3} $ whre i,j,k  are the node numbers, $w_{ij}$ is the edge weight between nodes i and j, and $k_i$ is the number of neighbours of a node

I may be mistaken, but when looking at this, as well as the output from the toolbox that is commonly used in the field, it would seem like such metrics such as Strength and Clustering can be quantified for every individual node. The formula then used for quantifying the global metric, say for strength and clustering is defined as:

Global Strength:
$ S_{global} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i \epsilon N} S_i $

Global Clustering:
$ C_{global} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i \epsilon N} C_i $

The reference for this can be found in this paper: https://www.jneurosci.org/content/30/47/15915?ijkey=69432e4b6d55f92cf0a2b6e1c108dcbd7fb1b0bd&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha
It's a pretty popular paper in the neuroimaging field, and I think it's the one that really pushed forward the use of graph theory in neuroimaging analysis.

Comment: Is parecellating a network to specify a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of it? It isn't a word in my vocabulary. 

Comment: @Galen, yup, if anything it is synonymous to partitioning

Comment: "*all graphical metrics are calculated at the local node level, and then averaged up to get the "global" graph metric.*" This isn't accurate in a general mathematical context, but maybe it is right for the family of graphs that you study? Could you tell us more about the mathematical properties/constraints that these graphs you're interested in studying have?

Comment: @Galen I've edited the post to address your question under (In Response to Comment). I'm not sure if I have actually answered it since I'm not sure if there are unique mathematical properties of a correlation matrix that is then used as an adjancecy matrix (taking the magnitude as teh weights of edges). I hope I managed to clarify a bit, if not please let me know and I can try adding more detail where prompted.